# traffic to public nat 1:1 ip blocked from local lan network

Tags: iptables, nat, port-forwarding

I have the follow network configuration:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -> nat 1:1 -> 192.168.0.2 -> 80 port forward -> 192.168.0.10
       ^                           ^                                 ^
       |                           |                                 |
    internet                      VM1                               VM2
```

When i try to access xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 from a public device (eg my phone) all work fine so i get web page from 192.168.0.10:80

**Problem is:** When i try to access xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 from a lan client (eg 192.168.0.150 on the same network of VM1) i can't reach the webserver (192.168.0.10:80) the connection timeout.

Those are the configurations:

```
VM1 whith dev ens32 -> 192.168.0.2
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
/sbin/iptables -F
/sbin/iptables -t nat -F
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i ens32 --dport 80  -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.10:80
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i ens32 --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.10:443
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.0.10 --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.0.10 --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens32 -j MASQUERADE
```

**UPDATE:** recorded tcpdump trace of a request made from client (192.168.0.150)

```
16:48:16.227785 IP 192.168.0.150.47391 > 192.168.0.2.https: Flags [S], seq 3088549798, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 126143387 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
16:48:16.227869 IP 192.168.0.2.47391 > 192.168.0.10.https: Flags [S], seq 3088549798, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 126143387 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
16:48:16.228268 IP 192.168.0.10.https > 192.168.0.2.47391: Flags [S.], seq 371329525, ack 3088549799, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 378079 ecr 126143387,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:48:16.228296 IP 192.168.0.2.https > 192.168.0.150.47391: Flags [S.], seq 371329525, ack 3088549799, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 378079 ecr 126143387,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:48:16.234087 IP 192.168.0.150.47391 > 192.168.0.2.https: Flags [R], seq 3088549799, win 0, length 0
16:48:16.234113 IP 192.168.0.2.47391 > 192.168.0.10.https: Flags [R], seq 3088549799, win 0, length 0
16:48:16.466921 IP 192.168.0.150.47393 > 192.168.0.2.https: Flags [S], seq 1316556207, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 126143412 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
16:48:16.466969 IP 192.168.0.2.47393 > 192.168.0.10.https: Flags [S], seq 1316556207, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 126143412 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
16:48:16.467335 IP 192.168.0.10.https > 192.168.0.2.47393: Flags [S.], seq 1172572926, ack 1316556208, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 378138 ecr 126143412,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:48:16.467360 IP 192.168.0.2.https > 192.168.0.150.47393: Flags [S.], seq 1172572926, ack 1316556208, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 378138 ecr 126143412,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:48:16.469625 IP 192.168.0.150.47393 > 192.168.0.2.https: Flags [R], seq 1316556208, win 0, length 0
16:48:16.469642 IP 192.168.0.2.47393 > 192.168.0.10.https: Flags [R], seq 1316556208, win 0, length 0
16:48:17.211348 IP 192.168.0.150.47391 > 192.168.0.2.https: Flags [S], seq 3088549798, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 126143487 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
16:48:17.211406 IP 192.168.0.2.47391 > 192.168.0.10.https: Flags [S], seq 3088549798, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 126143487 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
16:48:17.211783 IP 192.168.0.10.https > 192.168.0.2.47391: Flags [S.], seq 386696842, ack 3088549799, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 378324 ecr 126143487,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:48:17.211807 IP 192.168.0.2.https > 192.168.0.150.47391: Flags [S.], seq 386696842, ack 3088549799, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 378324 ecr 126143487,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:48:17.214283 IP 192.168.0.150.47391 > 192.168.0.2.https: Flags [R], seq 3088549799, win 0, length 0
16:48:17.214301 IP 192.168.0.2.47391 > 192.168.0.10.https: Flags [R], seq 3088549799, win 0, length 0
16:48:17.472667 IP 192.168.0.150.47393 > 192.168.0.2.https: Flags [S], seq 1316556207, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 126143512 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
16:48:17.472717 IP 192.168.0.2.47393 > 192.168.0.10.https: Flags [S], seq 1316556207, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 126143512 ecr 0,nop,wscale 9], length 0
16:48:17.473002 IP 192.168.0.10.https > 192.168.0.2.47393: Flags [S.], seq 1188287718, ack 1316556208, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 378390 ecr 126143512,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:48:17.473017 IP 192.168.0.2.https > 192.168.0.150.47393: Flags [S.], seq 1188287718, ack 1316556208, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 378390 ecr 126143512,nop,wscale 7], length 0
16:48:17.476317 IP 192.168.0.150.47393 > 192.168.0.2.https: Flags [R], seq 1316556208, win 0, length 0
16:48:17.476343 IP 192.168.0.2.47393 > 192.168.0.10.https: Flags [R], seq 1316556208, win 0, length 0
```

Comment: Looks like a [hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning) issue.

Comment: Can you tell what's the default gateway for these 3 systems: 192.168.0.2 , 192.168.0.10, 192.168.0.150? Is it for all of them the actual router doing nat 1:1 which could be for example 192.168.0.1 or are some of them using 192.168.0.2? That's to see what's possible in this setup

Comment: The gateway for all 3 systems is 192.168.0.1

Comment: Really it all depends on the router, not on VM1 which gets in a case of a server when considering hairpinning. You have to check that 1/ the router can't simply have an hairpinning setting activated: problem solved 2/ the router really dnat + forwards traffic from 192.168.0.150 to 192.168.0.2 and not just drop it. Use tcpdump on VM1 to verify this. 3/ the router will behave as wished when trying to workaround hairpinning. You have to check 1/ and verify 2/ . For 3 that would be after.

Comment: Never mind, the further I dig the further I see corner cases that would require more questions. I'm not going further.